# ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'empty' (T_EMPTY), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php

Hey i keep getting an syntax error in my code but i see absolutly nothing wrong, maybe a second set of eyes will help.

```
<?php

namespace SyzerPHP\Environment;
/**
 * Config.
 */
class Config extends Environment
{
    /**
     * validate().
     *
     * Validate the config array.
     *
     * @param array $conf The config array.
     *
     * @throws DomainException          If `$conf` argument is empty.
     * @throws DomainException          If `$conf` argument does not have a depth of 2.
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException If a section is not the start of an array.
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException If the section variable names are not capital letters.
     * @throws LengthException          If the section variable name and/or value is too long.
     *
     * @return void.
     */
    public static function validate(array $conf): void
    {
        if (\empty($conf)) {
            throw new Exception\DomainException('The config array is empty.');
        }
        if (\depth($conf) != 2) {
            throw new Exception\DomainException(\sprintf(
                'The config array does not have a depth of 2. Depth: `%s`.',
                (string) \depth($conf)
            ));
        }
        foreach ($conf as $var => $val) {
            if (!\is_array($val)) {
                throw new Exception\UnexpectedValueException(\sprintf(
                    'The section is not the start of an array. Passed: `%s`.',
                    \e($var)
                ));
            }
            foreach ($val as $var2 => $val2) {
                if (!\ctype_upper(\str_replace('_', '', $var2))) {
                    throw new Exception\UnexpectedValueException(\sprintf(
                        'The section variable name must all be caps. Passed: `%s`.',
                        \e($var2)
                    ));
                }
                if (\strlen($var2) > 30 || \strlen($val2) > 250) {
                    throw new Exception\LengthException(sprintf(
                        'The `$var2` and/or `$val2` variable is too long. Passed: `$var2` = `%s` `$val2` = `%s`.',
                        (string) \strlen($var2),
                        (string) \strlen($val2)
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
        self::clearConfig();
        self::$conf = $conf;
    }
}
```

The stack trace leads to this line `if (\empty($conf)) {`. I see no errors with the code. The php engine is expecting an identifier. As far as i am concerned i am missing no brackets, parenthesis, or any other symbol. The `\` at the beginning of a function is to prevent substitution attacks. Also keep in mind this is php `7.2` syntax. If i missed an error please any help would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `empty()` is a function, not part of a namespace. Same thing goes for a few others.

Comment: Nowhere in the manual https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php do they mention namespacing syntax.

Comment: It should still work because as detailed here https://github.com/simcop2387/underhanded-crypto/blob/master/ScottArcizewski/email-exerpt.txt

Comment: I must be misleaded

Comment: `empty` is more of an operator/language construct, not a function. That's why it can't be masked by namespacing.

Comment: Just tested with out the slash and it still does not work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the backslash for:

- empty
- depth
- is_array
- ctype_upper
- strlen
- sprintf
- str_replace
- e

Basically, every function you are calling.

Those are PHP native functions. When using `\something` means you are trying to point to some namespace.

Comment: Then how is `\bin2hex(\random_bytes(10)` able to work? I am confused

Comment: forgot about this `\ `  ... `bin2hex(random_bytes(10))` is what you want.

Comment: https://prntscr.com/i1vdo9 https://prntscr.com/i1vdof

Comment: That means now it works?

Comment: I mean travis ci said nothing was wrong with it, that is why i am confused.

Comment: https://github.com/paragonie/constant_time_encoding/blob/master/src/Binary.php notice the use of it in this file. Tested code that works

Comment: Works from PHP > 7. Is travis CI and your machine with php > 7?

Comment: It is supposed to prevent substitution attacks so other dependencies can not substitute the native php function with something else. All my other code works using this except this file. I am confused

Comment: My xampp apache server is running on php `7.2` and travis ci is testing my code on php `7.2`. Tested on both linux and windows

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: No error if i do not use the config class above. When i do use it it says `ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'empty' (T_EMPTY), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`.

Comment: My other classes work no problem usnig this method

Comment: This is another example that works https://www.hastebin.com/atagocufac.xml

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work with `\empty`. Just remove for this function and see what happens.

Comment: Ill try it out later i have work

Comment: Guess it only works on some functions

Comment: Ill create a work around to patch the security hole

Comment: And it still shows the error i do not use the `\`.